# How to stop passing duplicate parameters for checkbox in query string - Razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

How to stop passing duplicate parameters of checkbox in querystring .When i check the checkbox,it will pass true value as well as false value like this.

> https://localhost:44392/RequestSummary?SearchString=&**CompletedRequest=true**&OpenRequest=false&**CompletedRequest=false**&ImplementedRequest=false

Because of this im getting error in my page

> ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
> Key: CompletedRequest

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Teena

Answer (score 0):

The `false` option is generated by a tag helper. If you don't want the false option, use plain HTML for your checkbox, not the tag helper.

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/checkboxes

Comment: Hi @MiKe Brind, if i use plain checkbox without taghelper then how i can get the value of checkbox in my on get method.Could you please elaborate this?

Comment: The value will be bound to a public property or parameter that has the same name as whatever you apply the the `name` attribute on the input.

Comment: Can you give an example of what this should look like?

Comment: @NickyLarson There are examples at the link I provided: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/checkboxes#checkbox-basics